# Generic.List - how does the Contains function work?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5

I have two Generic Lists with the same objects Type `T` within them. For example
`oGenList1.Items(0)` is the same as `oGenList2.Items(3)` (their properties have the same values, etc).
I'm doing something like this:

```
oGenList2.Contains(oGenList1.Items(0))
```

It always shows `false`; I don't understand why. Do you have any idea?
Do I have to define any comparer for class `T` to force this function to work properly?

I've already added Equals function and it still doesn't work. :(
I've made a simple simulation of my situation in very simple project and it works.
But my situation is more complex. My classes inherit from other ones etc.
Any idea why it may not work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just going with your type's `Equals` method by default. You don't need to define a custom comparer; if your scenario is this simple (you just want `Contains` to behave properly), simply override your type's `Equals` method to compare two objects for equality based on the criteria you want and you should be good. (Oh, and if you're overriding `Equals`, you should also override `GetHashCode`).

Basic example:

```
class X : IEquatable<X>
{
    public int Value { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(X other)
    {
        return other != null && other.Value == Value;
    }

    // This is the main part you need to do. Otherwise by default
    // object.Equals just tests for reference equality.
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as X);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return Value;
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var list1 = new List<X> { new X { Value = 1 } };
        var list2 = new List<X> { new X { Value = 1 } };

        // Since type X overrides the Equals method to test
        // the equality of two instances' properties, this line
        // outputs True.
        Console.WriteLine(list2.Contains(list1[0]));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, this will use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to do the comparison. This first tests to see if your type `T` implements `IEquatable<T>` - if so it will use that interface and the `Equals(T)` method. Otherwise it will just use `object.Equals(object)` (note that it also takes into account `null`s and `Nullable<T>`, so you don't have to).

By default, this means that *classes* will be treated as equal only if they are the same instance (structs are compared at the field level). If you override `Equals` you should get the behaviour you expect, but note that if you override `Equals` you should also override `GetHashCode` to have a similar implementation.